# AES encryption changes file size in Java

Tags: java, aes, filesize

I am trying to encrypt all .class files inside a jar file with AES. After the encrypt process, I write it to a new .jar file. But the output file size doubles. Is it normal for AES encryption to change the file size this much?

in file: 8.914.293 bytes - out file: 19.023.321 bytes

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, 0, aesKeyBytes.length, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivSpec);
            
    File sourceFile = new File("C:\\test\\test.jar");
    File encryptFile = new File("C:\\test\\testOUT.jar");
    encrypt(cipher, sourceFile, encryptFile);
}

private static void encrypt(Cipher cipher, File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws Exception {
    targetFile.delete();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    
    FileOutputStream dst_fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    JarOutputStream dst_jar = new JarOutputStream(dst_fos);
    
    JarFile src_jar = new JarFile(sourceFile);
    for (Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = src_jar.entries(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
        JarEntry entry = enumeration.nextElement();

        InputStream is = src_jar.getInputStream(entry);
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

        String name = entry.getName();
        if(name.endsWith(".class")){
            try {
                bytes = encryptBytes(cipher, bytes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        JarEntry ne = new JarEntry(name);
        dst_jar.putNextEntry(ne);
        dst_jar.write(bytes);
        baos.reset();
    }
    src_jar.close();

    dst_jar.close();
    dst_fos.close();
}

private static byte[] encryptBytes(Cipher cipher, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
    return encryptedData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not normal for just encryption to increase the file size significantly.

There is a slight overhead as mentioned by @mahdi hashemi, but this is typically between 16-32 bytes per encryption "session". I haven't studied the code in detail, but normally you should generate a random initialization vector which is the same size as the block size, 16 bytes, and store with the encrypted data and then for CBC with PKCS5 padding up to an additional 16 bytes. Strictly speaking you can't have PKCS5 padding with AES, I'm assuming it in fact will be the logical extension called PKCS7. So, up to 32 bytes of overhead per encryption session, or segment is normal. (You should be specifying PCKS7 as padding for AES).

It is not normal for it to increase to twice the size, you're doing something wrong in the code.

And, no, it has no effect whatsoever on the output size what chunk size you read the input with - one byte or everything. AES CBC works the same, and the slight increase memory use when reading a lot of data has no effect on the output size - provided of course there are no bugs in the code related to the chunking, but then it's the bug that's causing the expansion, not the chunking or not.

The actual reason behind the expansion is likely that .jar files are in fact a form of compressed zip-archives, and you're reading it as a decompressed stream and then encrypting the decompressed stream, so your encrypted file is probably missing out on the compression "built in" in jar-files.

Comment: +1 (lack of) compression; Java classes compress well, but encrypted data (with modern algorithms) generally does not compress at all. Other factors that could apply to this title but not the full Q are: some schemes add authentication (typically 8-16 more bytes), some add other metadata (varies, a lot), and some optionally (PGP, S/MIME, openssl 'enc') or always (JWE, XMLenc) base64-encode the result which makes it about 34% bigger.

Comment: When designing encryption applications, it's in fact best to include compression in the process, *before* the encryption step. For example, our file encryption software https://www.axantum.com/xecrets-file-ez does just that - zipping the data stream before encryption. It also to some extent strengthens the encryption, increasing the difficulty in performing known plain text attacks. Any subsequent encoding, such as base64, would then be the last step, if the transport medium requires it, and is really outside the scope of the encryption as such.

Comment: @Xecrets
When I try to compress the output .jar file with popular compression methods such as 7zip, zip, the size still does not decrease. I guess I should compress each .class files myself before aes encrypt. Do you have another suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, compression requires redundancy in the data. Properly encrypted data is essentially indistinguishable from random data, and can't be compressed. So pickup the class, compress it, then encrypt it and then store it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you read compressed data, which will get decompressed once it is read. After that you encrypt the "plaintext" data, which will randomize the data. When you put back the files, the compression routine won't be able to compress this randomized data. So yes, you would expect the .jar file to grow in size. If you'd encrypt the .jar file itself then you would not get a large increase of size.

Note that you do not seem to use authenticated encryption nor do you store a randomized IV. That means that your implementation is not as secure as it could be.

Comment: +1 on the IV, as mentioned previously. What do you mean with "authenticated encryption"? Maybe you refer to the inclusion of an HMAC, i.e. a keyed hash to ensure the integrity of the encrypted data. It's of course a good idea, but it does not change the difficulty to break the encryption as such, but does ensure that the data is exactly as originally.

Comment: Yes, HMAC would be a very secure possibility (assuming that the IV is included, if the IV included with the message). However, generally we'd use a scheme such as AES-GCM nowadays. That's a reasonable scheme as long as the file sizes don't grow too large.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal for AES encryption to increase the file size. The reason for this is that encryption algorithms, including AES, add some additional bytes to the output, which are required for security reasons. Additionally, the padding scheme you are using (PKCS5Padding) may add extra bytes to the plaintext to ensure that the data being encrypted is a multiple of the block size of the cipher. This can result in an increase in the output size, especially for small files.

In your code, you are also using a ByteArrayOutputStream to read the entire contents of each JarEntry into memory before encrypting it. This can cause memory issues for large files, and may also be contributing to the increase in file size. Instead, you can read and encrypt the data in chunks, writing each chunk out to the output stream as you go. This will help to keep memory usage low and reduce the overall size of the output file.

Here is an updated version of your code that reads and encrypts the data in chunks:
java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, 0, aesKeyBytes.length, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivSpec);
            
    File sourceFile = new File("C:\\test\\test.jar");
    File encryptFile = new File("C:\\test\\testOUT.jar");
    encrypt(cipher, sourceFile, encryptFile);
}

private static void encrypt(Cipher cipher, File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws Exception {
    targetFile.delete();

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    
    FileOutputStream dst_fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    JarOutputStream dst_jar = new JarOutputStream(dst_fos);
    
    JarFile src_jar = new JarFile(sourceFile);
    for (Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = src_jar.entries(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
        JarEntry entry = enumeration.nextElement();

        InputStream is = src_jar.getInputStream(entry);

        String name = entry.getName();
        if(name.endsWith(".class")){
            JarEntry ne = new JarEntry(name);
            dst_jar.putNextEntry(ne);
            
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                byte[] encryptedData = cipher.update(buf, 0, len);
                dst_jar.write(encryptedData);
            }
            byte[] finalEncryptedData = cipher.doFinal();
            dst_jar.write(finalEncryptedData);
        } else {
            JarEntry ne = new JarEntry(name);
            dst_jar.putNextEntry(ne);
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                dst_jar.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        is.close();
        dst_jar.closeEntry();
    }
    src_jar.close();

    dst_jar.close();
    dst_fos.close();
}
```

In this updated code, the input stream is read in chunks of 1024 bytes, and each chunk is encrypted and written to the output stream as it is read. The final chunk is encrypted using the doFinal() method, which ensures that any remaining bytes are properly encrypted and added to the output. This approach should help to reduce memory usage and minimize the increase in file size.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT